# ASP.NET Session - Change settings depending on browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I want to dynamically change the settings of the session information depending on the browser, essentially I want safari user's to use cookieless session and non safari user's to use cookie based session (cf safari cross domain cookie policy!).

I know I can use "UseDeviceProfile" for this, but all I want to do is set it to true for safari (I also want to set regenerateExpiredSessionId to true for safari as well, but I suppose this can be default to true since if regenerateExpiredSessionId is true and cookieless  is false then it should'nt make any difference should it?).

Would I need to create a new browser profile for this? How can go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Note the "cf". I have developed a facebook application, session does not work with newer versions of safari when used in conjunction with cookies due to their cross domain cookie policy (the facebook application is within an iframe). Thats why I want to use cookieless session management with safari.